# How to record the first instance of an observation by group?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a dataset that consists of library check-out data. It records the exact date and time when an item was checked out. Over the time-span of the data, new items enter the dataset and are checked out for the first time. The items change their classification from time to time. This is what I'm interested in. So what I'd like to do is to take my dataset and create a new dataset that records a value for each of the items for (the beginning of) every week.

### Data

```
library(dplyr)

# Simulate data
set.seed(1)
item <- rep(1:10, each = 10)
timedate <- as.POSIXct("2010-01-01 00:00:00") + runif(n=100, min=0, max=31*24*60*60)
classification <-  sample(c(NA, letters[1:4]), 100, replace = T)
my_df <- tibble(item, timedate, classification) %>% 
  # Taking a random subset by group
  group_nest(item, keep= TRUE)  %>% 
  add_column(mysamples = sample(6:10, 10, replace = T)) %>% 
  mutate(sampled  = map2(data , mysamples, ~ sample_n(.x, .y))) %>%
  .$sampled %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  arrange(item, timedate)

# This is what my simulated data looks like
my_df

   item            timedate classification
1     1 2010-01-02 21:58:08              a
2     1 2010-01-07 06:03:04              d
3     1 2010-01-12 12:51:36              c
4     1 2010-01-20 12:03:39              a
5     1 2010-01-21 11:38:00              b
6     1 2010-01-28 20:24:06           <NA>
7     1 2010-01-29 03:42:23              d
8     1 2010-01-30 06:50:18           <NA>
9     2 2010-01-06 11:21:29              a
10    2 2010-01-07 09:14:42              b
11    2 2010-01-12 18:44:46              b
12    2 2010-01-12 21:46:23              b
13    2 2010-01-16 10:17:17              a
14    2 2010-01-22 07:08:41              c
15    2 2010-01-23 05:54:29              a
```

### Objective

Using the example of the first 5 weeks

```
week <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-02-01"), 7)
```

These are the instructions that I think need to be done to achieve what I want:

1. pick a week interval (start with the first)
2. do the following for all items
3. if a given item was checked out during the interval, sort the item by all of its check-out dates, then return the class of the first checkout date. Since the dataset has recorded some classes as NA, this class may be a letter or NA.
4. if the item was not checked out during the week interval check whether the item has been checked out before. if so, return the last available class
5. if the item has not been checked out during any previous interval, return "never checked out"
6. repeat for all week intervals

In total, the new dataset should contain `length(week)*length(unique(item))` rows.

It will look like the following:

```
item                week classification
   1                   1              a
   1                   2              c
   1                   3              a
   1                   4              NA
   1                   5              d
   ... # looking for the first case where there is no observation in week 1
   8                   1              "never checked out"
   8                   2              b
```

### What I've done so far

The closest I have gotten so far is to use the interval function in the lubridate package. I have created some intervals using the following function, now what's left is to check whether in any particular interval an item has a new classification, if so, use it, if not use the old one, if that doesn't exist code as "never checked out".

```
library(lubridate)

myintervals <- map2(head(week, -1), tail(week, -1), function(x,y ) interval(x,y-1))

### Here I just filter out those observations which have multiples of the same date. Not sure if I'm on the right track.

my_df %>%
  group_by(item, as.Date(timedate)) %>% 
  filter(timedate == min(timedate))
```

Note, that [Akruns response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66125130/3540149) is not using my simulated data and therefore does not work for my case.

Comment: Do you want to add a column 'week'?

Comment: Yes, such that it overrides the datetime and the classification should only match the first value that is within the week interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#using only my_df from above - NOT the week object

my_df %>%
  mutate(week = week(timedate), #generate week variable
         year = year(timedate), #not called for, but probably useful,
         classification = ifelse(is.na(classification), "NA", classification) #convert NA to character NA, to handle step 4
  ) %>%
  group_by(item, week) %>% #step 2, 1
  arrange(timedate) %>% #step 3
  summarize(new_class = first(classification)) %>% #step 3
  ungroup() %>% #cleanse
  complete(item, week) %>% #expand the df for all item-weeks
  group_by(item) %>% arrange(week) %>% #prep for 4
  fill(new_class, .direction = "down") %>% #step 4 - fill downwards
  mutate(new_class = replace_na(new_class, "never checked out")) %>% #step 5 %>%
  ungroup() %>% #cleanse
  arrange(item, week)  #match display 
#for multi-year data, anytime you group by week also group by year
```

Comment: You should probably `complete()` by `year`, too, now that I think about it.

Comment: Good to know, for the mock data perhaps not necessary but for my actual data it is.

Answer (score 1):

We can do the `bind_rows` after creating the 'week' column

```
out <- tibble(item, timedate, classification) %>%
  group_nest(item, keep= TRUE)  %>% 
  add_column(mysamples = sample(6:10, 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(sampled  = map2(data , mysamples, ~ sample_n(.x, .y))) %>%
  pull(sampled) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
        slice(seq_len(length(week))) %>%
        mutate(classification = replace(classification, 
         cumsum(!is.na(classification)) == 0, 'never checked out'),
        week = week)) 



tail(out, 15)
# A tibble: 15 x 4
    item timedate            classification    week      
   <int> <dttm>              <chr>             <date>    
 1     8 2010-01-25 02:19:35 never checked out 2010-01-01
 2     8 2010-01-11 12:16:12 never checked out 2010-01-08
 3     8 2010-01-15 18:24:19 b                 2010-01-15
 4     8 2010-01-30 18:41:59 a                 2010-01-22
 5     8 2010-01-28 15:47:44 b                 2010-01-29
 6     9 2010-01-11 02:03:43 c                 2010-01-01
 7     9 2010-01-13 09:35:44 a                 2010-01-08
 8     9 2010-01-23 02:06:39 a                 2010-01-15
 9     9 2010-01-14 11:23:11 c                 2010-01-22
10     9 2010-01-23 01:04:27 d                 2010-01-29
11    10 2010-01-13 17:06:09 c                 2010-01-01
12    10 2010-01-25 03:30:45 b                 2010-01-08
13    10 2010-01-28 03:56:39 <NA>              2010-01-15
14    10 2010-01-02 19:50:49 c                 2010-01-22
15    10 2010-01-15 02:43:27 <NA>              2010-01-29
```

Comment: Does the slice just get rid of all the subsequent classifications within the week interval? This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @TeaTree It is based on the `length` of week.  So, it subsets only until the length of week and not over it

Comment: @TeaTree is it not the expected output?

Comment: What do we do about cases that have never been checked out? They should get a special (non-NA) value.

Comment: @TeaTree Do you want to replace those `NA` with `never checked out`

Comment: @TeaTree e.g. in the list element 9, the second row for 'classification is NA while in 10, the first 3 are NA.  Do you want to change those to 'never checked out'

Comment: Not quite. I want one row for every week for every group. It should take the value of the first classification (either a letter or NA) if it exists and it should a special non-NA value (e.g. "never checked out") if there is no observation for that week.

Comment: @TeaTree What about for element 10, it has first 3 observations NA

Comment: There are NAs in the original dataset and they should be treated as any other letter. For your example (item 10), it should be "never checked out" three times and then two times the letter values.

Comment: @TeaTree We are doing `sample`ing in each run without a set.seed, so the values may be different

Comment: It's not showing the "never checked out" for the items. Also, it's also not showing the correct classification by week anymore.

Comment: @TeaTree As I said earlier, there is a `sample`ing going on in each run.  So, your result would change.  I updated the output I am getting

Comment: Why don't the values in timedate not line up with those in week? E.g. ```6 9 2010-01-11 02:03:43 c 2010-01-01```

Comment: @TeaTree Is it based on the output from `sample_n` which is returning a sample of rows in random order and that part of the code is from your post

Comment: @TeaTree I am not sure how you want to sample the rows.  After sampling, you get a random order.  May be you need `arrange(timedate)` before the `slice`

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Yes, I think that's what I want/need. Thank you!

Comment: OK, now when I'm trying to use this solution for my actual data, I get the error "no applicable method for 'slice' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')". Even when I use ```dplyr::slice(seq_len(length(week)))``` Any idea why?

Comment: @TeaTree That would be case where some `list` elements are not a data.frame or tibble.  Can you check `lst1 <- tibble(item, timedate, classification) %>%
  group_nest(item, keep= TRUE)  %>% 
  add_column(mysamples = sample(6:10, 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(sampled  = map2(data , mysamples, ~ sample_n(.x, .y))) %>%
  pull(sampled); keep(lst1, ~ is.data.frame(.x) & nrow(.x) > 0) %>% map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
        slice(seq_len(length(week))) %>%...`

Comment: In my actual data, I just have one large data frame. Making a list of dataframes was just so I could remove some observations from each group in my MWE. When I run your code, I get one dataframe with the expected output and no error.

Comment: @TeaTree In the above comment.  I split up the code so as to investigate.  i.e. after you `pull` the 'sampled' as a `list`.  we are using `keep` to keep only those data that are data.frame and where the number of rows are greater than 0, and then apply the `map_dfr`.  It is possible that some group doesn't have enough rows and this may be one of the resaon.   Is is better to check after `group_nest` operation

Comment: I mean my actual dataframe does not have a group_nest. It looks just like when you run the data-creation code that I originally posted ("my_df").

Comment: @TeaTree So, I guess this example was just created to mimic your data.  But, your data is the one with `my_df` i.e. the rbinded one?

Comment: It looks very similar, although it's a vast dataset >500k rows.

Comment: @TeaTree I meant whether your original data is after the `bind_rows` specified in your code or not

Comment: After the ```arrange(item, timedate)```, yes.

Comment: @TeaTree can you check `my_df %>% count(item) %>% filter(n < length(week))`

Comment: @TeaTree But, the `slice` step is done just after we pull the column 'sampled'

Comment: I get 
```# A tibble: 10 x 2
    item     n
   <int> <int>
 1     1     7
 2     2     8
 3     3     8
 4     4     8
 5     5    10
 6     6     8
 7     7     7
 8     8     6
 9     9    10
10    10     9```

Comment: @TeaTree may be there are some cases where the 'n' is less than the length of week.

Comment: My original dataset spans 15 years, so the length of the week is 787. All item counts are less than that.

Comment: @TeaTree If you can subset a data that throws the error and use `dput` to show the data, it would be easier to check

Comment: I think one of the problems is that my data looks different from the one you used. My data isn't nested. I only have a nested clause in my code to simulate my data. Could you start after I have specified ```my_df``` and adapt your answer to that data? Perhaps that resolves the issue. I feel like it won't be productive if I post my dput at this point because the data is different.